# Contact form white page of death

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

When I try to get my contact form working, my browser crashes and sends me a white page. I have found the reason, but I cannot understand what is wrong.

```
//getting fields 
        $naam = $_POST['naam'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $adres = $_POST['adres'];
        $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
        $telefoon = $_POST['telefoon'];
        $iban = $_POST['iban'];
        $15 = $_POST['15'];
        $20 = $_POST['20'];
        $25 = $_POST['25'];
        $30 = $_POST['30'];
        $anderbedrag = $_POST['anderbedrag'];

        //message to webmaster

        $message = $naam;

        $message .= "jaarlijks bijdrage: ";
        if ($15 != null){
            $message .= '15,-';
        }
        if ($15 != null){
            $message .= '20,-';
        }
        if ($15 != null){
            $message .= '25,-';
        }
        if ($15 != null){
            $message .= '30,-';
        }
        if ($anderbedrag != null){
            $message .= $anderbedrag;
        }
```

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: This code doesn't help us in providing you with help. This is just getting and setting variables, which can't really go wrong. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: enable error reporting (`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`). Php will tell you what's up.

Comment: A question: Are numbers as variable name allowed in Php?

Comment: good question @reporter: No is the answer, php.net: 'Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. '

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

So your variable names aren't valid (`$15` etc).

Besides that; always enable error reporting when developing. Php would have told you this.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```